# passing ciphers to libcurl through git?

Tags: git, https, libcurl

Environment: Fedora 15 x64 (yes, we are moving away from it), git 1.7.11.1.

We're hitting a problem with git clone which fails on an https repository because the cipher that's used by the Git server isn't enabled by default on the client.

We managed to replicate the problem with plain "curl -v" (curl 7.21.3, but git seems to be using its own copy):

```
curl -v https://git.repo.com
```

(the internal server name was replaced) fails like Git, but:

```
curl --cipher rsa_rc4_128_sha -v https://git.repo.com
```

succeeds.

The question now is how can we pass such a flag to libcurl which is used by Git. So far I haven't found such a way (google'd about libcurl, git, looked at Git's and libcurl's sources).

Comment: Looking further in the libcurl source, the `curl --cipher` command line flag sets `CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST`, which is not mentioned anywhere in the Git source code.

So so far it looks like it's just not supported. :(

Answer (score 2):

No, the option to specify the list of ciphers to libcurl is called [CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTSSLCIPHERLIST) but is not used by git.

You would need to modify the git source code to introduce this feature. Shouldn't be too hard and possibly you can convince the [git project](http://git-scm.com/) to accept this change for the future!

Answer (score 2):

## Git support for choosing SSL ciphers

Since Git version 2.5.0 ([see release notes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.5.0.txt#L85)) you can use the `http.sslCipherList` git configuration variable to do this. If you are able to upgrade your Git version this is the best way to accomplish passing a list of ciphers to libcURL via Git.

The `http.sslCipherList` variable is described as follows within Git's documentation:

> A list of SSL ciphers to use when negotiating an SSL connection. The available ciphers depend on whether libcurl was built against NSS or OpenSSL and the particular configuration of the crypto library in use. Internally this sets the `CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST` option; see [the libcurl documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST.html) for more details on the format of this list.

### Git command

To set the cipher list globally for Git you would run:

`git config --global http.sslCipherList "<List of Cipher Identifiers>"`

It is **extremely important** to understand that **the cipher identifiers accepted by cURL differ based upon the SSL library cURL has been linked against**! That makes this configuration value non-portable between all installations of cURL which differ in their linked SSL library.

Additionally, while I have linked back-end specific documentation below, **only the cURL documentation on cipher identifiers is reliable** because the cURL developers did not perfectly reproduce the various identifiers for each back-end as detailed in [this mailing list thread](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2016-05/0093.html).

## Resources

- [The git config section for `http.sslCipherList`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-httpsslCipherList)
- [The cURL man page for the CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST variable](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST.html)
- [The cURL ciphers for all back-ends (reliable)](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/ssl-ciphers.html)
- [cipher supported by the openSSL back-end](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/ciphers.html)
- [mod_NSS ciphers supported by the NSS back-end](https://pagure.io/mod_nss/blob/master/f/docs/mod_nss.html#_589)
- [mod_SSL ciphers supported by the NSS back-end](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslciphersuite)

Comment: Good summary. +1 That comes from Git 2.5+ (Q2 2015): https://stackoverflow.com/a/30442395/6309

Comment: I just thought to look that up after I posted and I came back to find you already did the legwork for me. Wish I'd seen your comment before I looked the introduction version up myself! I've edited the answer to include reference to the required git version.

Comment: No problem: I have been doing that kind of legwork (about new Git features) for a looong time now.