# Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s)

Tags: git, algorithm, encryption, fedora20

I am a fedora 20 user. While cloning a repository,I got the following error:
" Cloning into 'git_missions'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://openhatch.org/git-mission-data/git/hithard/': Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s).  "

I am not getting what to do?need help.

Comment: You will be able to pass a cipher list to curl in git with Git 2.5+° (Q2 2015). See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30442395/6309)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest solution is just to use `http` instead of `https`:

```
$ git clone http://openhatch.org/git-mission-data/git/hithard/
Cloning into 'hithard'...
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

I think the error itself ("no common encryption algorithms") is accurate; it appears that the server wants to use some sort of elliptic curve cipher (TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256) that is not supported by git's underlying SSL library.  You can use something like `wireshark` to capture the SSL handshake between git and the server and see the options being passed back and forth.

At least on my system, `curl` does not seem to support this cipher, and `git` uses `libcurl` for handling https/http connections.

**Update**

So, based on my last comment to @mattdm, in which I discovered that `curl` on my system is using the NSS crypto library, the following works:

```
curl --ciphers ecdhe_ecdsa_aes_128_gcm_sha_256 https://openhatch.org/
```

Unfortunately, there isn't any way to pass a cipher list to `git`.  The patch to make it do so is trivial -- [here is one version I just made](https://github.com/larsks/git/compare/master...feature/ssl-cipher-list) -- but I don't know what the odds are of getting this accepted upstream.

Comment: Wow!! Thanks.But I really want to know why this worked but not "https"

Comment: @mattdm, it looks like on Fedora at least that `curl` is using the NSS crypto library rather than OpenSSL. At least, only values from the "NSSCipherSuite" of [this document](https://git.fedorahosted.org/cgit/mod_nss.git/plain/docs/mod_nss.html) seem to work.

Comment: I've had a [patch accepted to git](https://github.com/git/git/commit/55764cec3ec09f888610da47f850d3248fe9cb9d) that addresses this issue.

Comment: Congratulation. The patch has now been merged. I had actually written the all answer below before realizing that you were the author of the patch!

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately, there isn't any way to pass a cipher list to git

[`larsks`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147356/larsks) mentioned [in the comments](https://github.com/git/git/commit/55764cec3ec09f888610da47f850d3248fe9cb9d):

> I've had a patch accepted to git that addresses this issue

That has been indeed accepted, and merge in Git 2.5+ (Q2 2015)

See [commit f6f2a9e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f6f2a9e42d14e61429af418d8038aa67049b3821) by [Lars Kellogg-Stedman (`larsks`)](https://github.com/larsks), 08 May 2015.
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 39fa791](https://github.com/git/git/commit/39fa79178feb1ce72050ebd21b9e34f158e8befa), 22 May 2015)</sup>

> ### `http`: add support for specifying an SSL cipher list
>
> Teach git about a new option, "`http.sslCipherList`", which permits one to
>   specify a list of ciphers to use when negotiating SSL connections.
>   The setting can be overridden by the `GIT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST` environment
>   variable.

The [`git config` man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f6f2a9e42d14e61429af418d8038aa67049b3821/Documentation/config.txt#L1564-L1575) now includes:

```
http.sslCipherList:
```

> A list of SSL ciphers to use when negotiating an SSL connection.
>   The available ciphers depend on whether libcurl was built against NSS or OpenSSL and the particular configuration of the crypto library in use.
>   Internally this sets the 'CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST' option; see the [libcurl documentation for more details on the format of this list](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST.html).
>
> Can be overridden by the '`GIT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST`' environment variable.
>   To force git to use libcurl's default cipher list and ignore any explicit `http.sslCipherList` option, set '`GIT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST`' to the empty string.

---

That can come in handy in 2015:

- "[Now that it is 2015, what SSL/TLS cipher suites should be used in a high security HTTPS environment?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/76993)"
- "[Hardening Your Web Server’s SSL Ciphers](https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/)"
- [Nick Craver](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver)'s [problems with SSL/TLS and productivity](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/601008290789781504), with a [now fixed security issue](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/601009146465509376) ([weakdh.org](https://weakdh.org/), the Logjam Attack exploiting a  weaknesses in how Diffie-Hellman key exchange has been deployed).

---

Update August 2015: Git 2.6+ (Q3 2015) will allow to specify the SSL version explicitly:

> ## `http`: add support for specifying the SSL version

See [commit 01861cb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/01861cb7a27b948bc0218877311f531f25386691) (14 Aug 2015) by [Elia Pinto (`devzero2000`)](https://github.com/devzero2000).
Helped-by: [Eric Sunshine (`sunshineco`)](https://github.com/sunshineco).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ed070a4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed070a40072f01aa819f114bf6b35edf0f53cab2), 26 Aug 2015)</sup>

```
http.sslVersion
```

> The SSL version to use when negotiating an SSL connection, if you want to force the default.
>   The available and default version depend on whether libcurl was built against NSS or OpenSSL and the particular configuration of the crypto library in use. Internally this sets the '`CURLOPT_SSL_VERSION`' option; see the libcurl documentation for more details on the format of this option and for the ssl version supported.
>   Actually the possible values of this option are:
>
> - sslv2
> - sslv3
> - tlsv1
> - tlsv1.0
> - tlsv1.1
> - tlsv1.2
>
> Can be overridden by the '`GIT_SSL_VERSION`' environment variable.
>   To force git to use libcurl's default ssl version and ignore any explicit `http.sslversion` option, set 'GIT_SSL_VERSION' to the empty string.