# Git on Windows not working with remote because of "SSL protocol" errors

Tags: windows, git, curl, github, msysgit

## tl;dr

Git on Windows stops connecting to github because of mysterious "SSL protocol" errors. Halp!

## The Issue

I'm developing on Windows, using a private GitHub repo for source control.  When I first boot my system, I'm able to access the remote repo without issue - `pull`, `push`, `fetch`, etc. all work just fine.

After some amount of time(*), this stops, and I get the following error:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/our-team/private-repo.git/': Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:443

(*) The amount of time seems variable - I've witnessed as little as an hour or two, up to a whole day.  Usually after coming back from the system sleeping, it seems to be an issue, but I don't know if it's caused by a time delay or by the system sleeping.

Checking via cURL, I get

```
λ curl -v "https://github.com/our-team/private-repo.git/"
*   Trying 192.30.252.130...
* Connected to github.com (192.30.252.130) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.0, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:443
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:443
```

Using `set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` with `git pull` shows similar information.  Sometimes it succeeds (see below), but most of the time it fails.

## Further Notes

There's a little bit of a sporadic nature to it - sometimes I can get requests to succeed, but once it starts exploding, it's generally broken 9 out of 10 requests or more.

A successful cURL request looks like:

```
λ curl -v "https://github.com/our-team/private-repo.git/"
*   Trying 192.30.252.130...
* Connected to github.com (192.30.252.130) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.0, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.0, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.0, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* TLSv1.0, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.0, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.0, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.0, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.0, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.0, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.0 / AES128-SHA
* Server certificate:
*        subject: businessCategory=Private Organization; 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US; 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=Delaware; serialNumber=5157550; street=548 4th Street; postalCode=94107; C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=GitHub, Inc.; CN=github.com
*        start date: 2014-04-08 00:00:00 GMT
*        expire date: 2016-04-12 12:00:00 GMT
*        subjectAltName: github.com matched
*        issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /our-team/private-repo.git/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.41.0
> Host: github.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: GitHub.com
< Date: Mon, 11 May 2015 15:19:43 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 178
< Location: https://github.com/our-team/private-repo/
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< X-Served-By: 76f8aa18dab86a06db6e70a0421dc28c
<
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host github.com left intact
```

## The Question

I've googled a good bit on trying to find this (over the course of several weeks, so I don't have links), but most suggestions seem to point at certificate errors or OpenSSL version mismatches / bugs (which wouldn't be sporadic like this AFAIK).

What might be causing this failure, and how can I resolve it?

## Relevant Software:

```
λ git --version
git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1

λ curl --version
curl 7.41.0 (i386-pc-win32) libcurl/7.41.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8zf zlib/1.2.8
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile SSPI Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM SSL libz
```

Comment: What happens if you use the redirect target url on the command line? "curl -v https://github.com/our-team/private-repo/"

Comment: @jthill - good thought!  It seemed to be much the same behavior.  Most of the time, the cURL calls fail.  When it finally succeeds with the SSL handshake, it returns a 404 (which is expected, since it's a private repo and I'm not sending credentials via cURL).  So the symptoms seem to remain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oddly, it turns out that the issue is that the laptop was throttled because of a weak power supply.  The docking station I was using was plugged into a low-amp powersupply (3.3 A), which, while it was compatible with the laptop, immediately kicked it into a heavily-throttled mode.

Apparently, this slowed everything down enough that the SSL handshake wasn't able to complete fast enough.

We *finally* tracked it down after reading a Dell support forum post (http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19363340) that discussed slowness issues.  The solution there was to change the power supply.

I had also experienced this slowness, but I did not think it was related.  We swapped to a high-amp power supply for the dock, and everything was fine again, and the SSL errors described above went away.

Comment: Good feedback, more precise than my answer. +1

Comment: Thanks for researching this issue. Just to add to the knowledge base, I was experiencing the same problems on a machine that had intermittent heavy load (I had a couple of virtual machines running the in background). Sometimes git push commands were failing (particularly if I was pushing from within IntelliJ IDEA), sometimes they were succeeding, but there was no obvious reason as to why. After reading your explanation, I shutdown the VMs and discovered that the commands succeeded nearly all the time. You would have thought that more robust SSL comms could be implemented...

Answer (score 3):

That looks like an error which could result from the security initiatives taken after the [Logjam attack -- `weakdh.org` --](https://weakdh.org/).
That resulted in the [suppression of some ciphers accepted in a SSL/TLS transaction](https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/).

Note that, as reported in "[Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30442395/6309)", you will be able to pass the right cipher list to curl *via* git.

Before that, you can also try if the issue persists while using a more recent Git for Windows (like the [Git 2.4.1](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases))

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Disabled my wifi connection and switched to cable and everything works again. Btw: Used a Dell in Docking-Station too.

Comment: Here I am seven years later with a Dell laptop with exactly the same problem.  On battery and wifi, I get this error.  Docked with power and a wired network connection and no error.